# Is - (- x) = x correct in floating point arithmetic?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Suppose `x` is a floating point number, I want to know whether `- ( - x)` equals to `x` in general?

Let us ignore corner cases such as x = max_floating_point_number / min_floating_number.

Comment: No. It's only approximately equal and you should compare with a tolerance. </sarcasm> (+1 for asking instead of just assuming witchcraft as some people do the moment they see floats)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I tend to agree with the answer given by Sneftel below (which is in contrast with your comment). If you change only the sign bit, and then change only the sign bit again, then you get the original value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, yes; negation of a floating-point value induces no error or loss of precision. (It just involves flipping a bit.)

The one exception to this is NaN. -(-(NaN)) is NaN, but NaN does not compare equal to any value, even another NaN. That's firmly in the realm of "corner cases", though.

Comment: Well, doesn't it depend on how floating points are encoded and what language are we talking about?

Comment: @Jefffrey No. I'm not aware of any computer floating-point representation which does not represent sign as a separate bit, and I strongly doubt one exists.

Answer (score 4):

You have not tagged your question with any programming language, so the answer is yes, according to the IEEE 754 standard, for any non-NaN floating-point value x, x = - (- x).

In some poorly implemented or poorly specified languages, `x` can have been computed as a non-NaN value and make `- (- x) == x` evaluate to false. This can happen when the compiler is allowed to compute some expressions with extra precision and the reduction from extra precision to the precision indicated by the type is poorly specified (C#) or poorly implemented (as happens with some C compilers). In this case, it is possible that `x` on the right-hand side keeps its extra-precise value while `- (- x)` is computed at the precision of the type, and the end result is that they are different.

Comment: Even if the negation were not performed in extended precision, are you aware of any compiler which would then upgrade the intermediate value to extended precision for the comparison?

Comment: @Sneftel The example is theoretical, but I guess that if optimizations are disabled, it can happen. Not converting to the precision of the type was what was reproached to GCC in the original bug reported as bug 323, if I remember correctly. Register spillage would have to occur for `- (- x)` to be computed as 64-bit, so it may take the form of a larger expression within which `-(-x)==x` occurs.

Comment: @Sneftel The “bug 323” I was referring to: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323 . If compiled with strict IEEE 754 semantics, the program in the bug report does NOT print “error”. Also if GCC converted to the precision of the type before comparing, the program would not print “error”. Thus the version of GCC against which this bug was reported *could* evaluate `- (-x) == x` as `0` under just right circumstances leading it to spill the computation but leave `x` in a register.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that the value of `x` will be *equivalent* to `-(-x)`?  In particular, if `x` is negative zero, will the latter expression yield positive zero or negative zero?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Ah, I see that page has been fixed since I'd read it before.  Still, it raises an interesting question of whether the unary `-` operator is rigidly defined as representing the result of subtracting `x` from positive zero, as opposed to multiplying it by -1.  If it represents the former, then it may be worth noting that while the IEEE equality relation will report `-(-x))` as equal to `x` in one case where it's *not* equivalent, and will report it as unequal in one case where it *is* equivalent.